# Got "Pipelining of requests forbidden" in c# rabbitmq client

Tags: c#, rabbitmq

I have a RabbitMQ C# Client running in a WCF service.

It catches `System.NotSupportedException: Pipelining of requests forbidden`  exception now and then.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Accroding to the [gudie](http://www.rabbitmq.com/dotnet-api-guide.html).You need to lock the channel for multi-threading.

> As a rule of thumb, IModel instances should not be used by more than one thread simultaneously: application code should maintain a clear notion of thread ownership for IModel instances.

Answer (score 5):

if the server doesn't have enough memory where RabbitMQ is installed you can experience this issue as well.

Answer (score 0):

If you declare a queue and reuse that channel to publish, this error may occur.
queue declare and pipeline a publish command before receiving a response.
It should be a defect of current sync api